# How to Configure owncloud like Dropbox, google drive? Restrict Users to a specified folder? Have a seperate folder for each user?

Tags: server, cloud, owncloud

I have installed owncloud at a server.
https://cloudybox.tk

How can I restrict user to a specified folder.
Like, if a user signup, then he can access only to a folder named by his username.

So that i can start an online cloud storage website.

Answer (score 0):

You should Nextcloud instead of Owncloud. It has more features, is more secure and fully open source. In Nextcloud you can put all users in one group and share a folder with this group. I think this is what you want.

Comment: I want like, Every user should have a seperate folder, and he/she should only be allowed to that folder.
Also he/she should be able to signup